# Calling a method from WS, parameter input type issue

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, vector

I have the following operation in a webservice interface:

```
[OperationContract]
  List<vCard> getVCards(int[] vCardIDs);
```

And I get this error when trying to write the code for calling it:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type missmatch just wrap your cardList into new ObservableCollection() where it is needed.
For e.g. just before call the service, 'course if it's following your program semantic

```
service.getVCardsAsync(new ObservableCollection<int>(cardList))
```

Comment: thank you, this was it, I will accept your answer in 3 minutes!